# Wildcard Loader function called multiple times (_load)

Tags: php, callback, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-hooks

I have a loader function which is called excessively whenever the user accesses the page. Naturally, I only need it to run once per page request, instead, it is called multiple times. Earlier the _load() ran only twice with MENU_CALLBACK, then I tested it with the default MENU_NORMAL_ITEM and it increased to four. Although I've changed it back, and cleared my cache, it still runs four times now, and I only want it to run once.

My question is, why is my loader function being called multiple times? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
$items['daycare/%isValid/home'] = array(
    'title' => 'Daycare Admin Home',
    'page callback' => 'daycares_home_page',
    'load arguments' => array(0),//Passes 1st part of url 'daycare' as 2nd arg
    'page arguments' => array(0),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);

function isValid_load($pageID, $pageType){
    /*Do stuff to validate wildcard part of URL. Will throw 404/403 if invalid*/
    return $pageId;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel)'s [`ddebug_backtrace()`](http://ratatosk.net/drupal/tutorials/debugging-drupal.html) function to see how/what is calling your load function.

```
function isValid_load($pageID, $pageType){
    ddebug_backtrace();
    ...
}
```

When you do, notice that the two calls can be traced back to the last two lines in [`index.php`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/index.php/7).  The first bootstraps  Drupal and initializes the theme while the second call actually does the work of rendering the page.  Though both actions seem to call the same [`_menu_translate()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/_menu_translate/7) which results in a call to your function.

As a side note, if you're concerned about performance, you might be interested in this [Lullabot article about caching](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/beginners-guide-caching-data-drupal-7).

I realize that this is a partial answer as I'm still getting familiar with the deepest workings of Drupal myself.  I welcome competing answers that can provide a clearer and more complete explanation of why the Drupal framework is structured in such a way that the _load function is called multiple times.

Comment: Your answer is still very helpful! Thanks Nmc. I'm going to try using backtrace. I'm not too concerned with performance, for just this. The actions I'll be handling within the _load() are fairly simple queries. Still, I've bookmarked the article for future use. :)

Comment: Another option would be to configure xdebug and push the code through a debugger, although sometimes it can be a bit tricky to configure.  You'd then be able to stick a breakpoint on your wildcard loader, examine values, look at call stack etc.